# iOS rxSwift: retryWhen updating refresh token

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have a static function calling a network service.
When the 400 response code happens I would like to redo the network call.

The current code is working, except that the refreshToken in the header does not update between one try and another.

I think that the problem is because the Observable created but the **request function** does not update at the retry.

I rode on the web that I should use a deferred method on the Observable, but I don't know how.

I've tried moving the code: `headers = [HeaderKeys.refreshToken.rawValue: "test test"]` anywhere but still it never makes a call with the "test test" refresh token. it always uses the old one.

How can I fix this?

```
 static func getAccessToken() -> Observable<GetAccessTokenResponse> {
            var retryCounter = 0
        let maxRetryCounter = 3
        let delayRetry = 10.0

        guard let refreshToken = NetworkHelper.shared.refreshToken else {
            return Observable.error(AuthenticationError.networkError)
        }

        var headers = [HeaderKeys.refreshToken.rawValue: refreshToken]


        return NetworkHelper.shared
            .request(url: CoreAPI.accessToken.url, request: nil, headers: headers, responseType: GetAccessTokenResponse.self, method: .get, encoding: nil)
            .catchError({ (error) -> Observable<(GetAccessTokenResponse?, Int)> in
                return Observable.error(AuthenticationError.networkError)
            })
            .flatMap({ (response) -> Observable<GetAccessTokenResponse> in
                // check http status code
                switch response.1 {
                case 200:
                    guard response.0?.accessToken != nil else {
                        return Observable.error(AuthenticationError.genericError)
                    }
                    // success
                    return Observable.just(response.0!)
                case 400:
                    // invalid parameters, refresh token not existing
                    return Observable.error(AuthenticationError.invalidParameters)
                case 404:
                    // user not existing
                    return Observable.error(AuthenticationError.userDoesntExist)
                default:
                    // by default return network error
                    return Observable.error(AuthenticationError.networkError)
                }
            })
            .retryWhen({ (errors) -> Observable<Void> in
                return errors
                    .do(onNext: { (error) in
                        headers = [HeaderKeys.refreshToken.rawValue: "test test"]
                    })
                    .flatMap({error -> Observable<Int> in
                        debugLog("Retrying get refresh token")
                        if retryCounter >= maxRetryCounter {
                            let authError = error as? AuthenticationError ?? .genericError
                            if authError == AuthenticationError.invalidParameters {
                                // publish logged false on subject
                                VDAAuthenticationManager.shared.logged.onNext(false)
                            }
                            return Observable.error(error)
                        }
                        // increase the retry counter and retry
                        retryCounter += 1
                        return Observable<Int>.timer(delayRetry, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
                })
                .flatMap ({ (_) -> Observable<Void> in
                    return Observable.just(())
                })
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the article [RxSwift and Retrying a Network Request Despite Having an Invalid Token](https://medium.com/@danielt1263/retrying-a-network-request-despite-having-an-invalid-token-b8b89340d29) I explain how to keep and update a token and how to handle retries when you get a 401 error. Using deferred is part of the answer.

In your particular case. It looks like you could use my service like this:

```
func getToken(lastResponse: GetAccessTokenResponse?) -> Observable<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)> {
    guard let refreshToken = lastResponse?.refreshToken else { return Observable.error(AuthenticationError.networkError) }
    var request = URLRequest(url: CoreAPI.accessToken.url)
    request.addValue(refreshToken, forHTTPHeaderField: HeaderKeys.refreshToken.rawValue)
    return URLSession.shared.rx.response(request: request)
}

func extractToken(data: Data) throws -> GetAccessTokenResponse {
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(GetAccessTokenResponse.self, from: data)
}

let tokenService = TokenAcquisitionService(initialToken: nil, getToken: getToken, extractToken: extractToken(data:))
```

In the above, you will have to pass a valid initialToken instead of `nil` or you will have to modify the `getToken` so it can get a token even if it doesn't have a refresh token.

An example of how to use deferred is below:

```
let response = Observable
    .deferred { tokenAcquisitionService.token.take(1) }
    .flatMap { makeRequest(withToken: $0) }
    .map { response in
        guard response.response.statusCode != 401 else { throw ResponseError.unauthorized }
        return response
    }
    .retryWhen { $0.renewToken(with: tokenAcquisitionService) }
```

I explain in the article what each line of code is for and how it works.

Comment: Hi Daniel, your code and your article are not so clear to me. Can you help me to implement my code with your solution.

Comment: I gave you an example above. Just replace `makeRequest(withToken:)` with a function that makes a request that needs a token. Make sure your function emits a `ResponseError.unauthorized` if the token is bad.

Comment: I'm having some problems with the get token and the extract token part... I just want to redo the same service call when 400 happens, with new refresh token fetched from a singleton class. I'm implementing a retry with the service that already fetch the new access token, but sometimes it's done in parallel and I just want to fetch the new updated refresh token from db to collect the new access token

Comment: I wonder, does this correctly handle situations when two requests are both send at the same time and both end in 401? Will there be one refresh request sent or two? If two refresh requests were sent, then there would be a race condition.

Comment: Yes it correctly handles multiple 401 situations. Just use the same tokenAcquisitionService object in the `renewToken` of every request. Only one request for a new token will be made and then all failed network requests will be retried when a new token is acquired.

Comment: I included a test harness in the gist that demonstrates the class' functionality.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your time! Everything is working!

Comment: @DanielT. Question, if I making a request with a token but the request fails because of the token how do I modify the urlRequests with the new token in the retry process?

Comment: @user2924482 As the article explains, you need to provide the code with a `makeRequest` function that takes in the token as a parameter and returns a URLRequest.

Comment: @DanielT. I post an example of my question in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188451/rxswift-modifying-urlrequest-if-request-fails-in-retrywhen